# Determine type/name of underlying file system

Tags: c, unix, filesystems, parallel-processing

Is there a way to programmatically determine the type(/name) of the underlying file system? The file system in this case can be a parallel file system like lustre/pvfs. So I need to query this name, and not the name of the underlying file system like ext3.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the `f_type` field from the `statfs()` function giving you?

Comment: I got 537068840 when I ran it on PVFS2. man page for statfs does not list PVFS as a file system

Comment: I suppose it will get a human-readable name now that orangefs is in the kernel but  that number comes from here:  #define PVFS2_SUPER_MAGIC 0x20030528

Answer (score 2):

Use **statfs** of **fstatfs** function to get the type (it is in **f_type** of the **statfs** structure). This type value gives you magic number which you can use to identify the file system. All the magic numbers are defined (at least on my system :)) in **/usr/include/linux/magic.h**, e.g.:

```
#define EXT3_SUPER_MAGIC    0xEF53
```